# Error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" al finalizar mi programa de Asistente de voz

Tags: python, python-3.x, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy trabajando en un asistente de voz en Python y he añadido varias funciones, pero últimamente cuando finaliza el programa me aparece el siguiente error y **no entiendo la verdad que significa**.

He estado buscando por internet pero no he encontrado por que se da el error, tampoco entiendo los archivos donde aparece el error, y lo de `NoneType object is not callable`.

No sé, hasta donde yo sé no estoy llamando nada. La traza completa del error es:

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function catch_errors. 
<locals>.call_with_this at 0x0000024DA7925040>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site- 
packages\comtypes\_comobject.py", line 91, in call_with_this
File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 
1474, in error
File "C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 
1699, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

No se que significa ya que el programa no estaba dando ese error y no tengo errores en el código, además de que todo parece que funciona bien.

Mi código:

```
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import speech_recognition as sr
import wikipedia
import smtplib #para emails
import webbrowser as wb 
import os
import pyautogui
import psutil
import pyjokes
import python_weather
import asyncio
from googletrans import Translator
import geocoder

engine= pyttsx3.init()
#Cambiar la voz
voz=engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voz[0].id) #0 español 1 en ingles
#la velocidad de hablar
velocidadvoz= 120
engine.setProperty("rate", velocidadvoz)
def hablar(audio):
 engine.say(audio)
 engine.runAndWait()

def Hora():
 hora=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S")
 hablar("La hora es")
 hablar(hora)

def Fecha():
 año= int(datetime.datetime.now().year)
 mes= int(datetime.datetime.now().month) 
 dia= int(datetime.datetime.now().day)
 hablar("La fecha actual es")
 hablar(dia)
 hablar(mes)
 hablar(año)

def Saludo():
 hablar("Bienvenido de vuelta, como esta?")
 tiempo= datetime.datetime.now().hour
 if tiempo>=6 and tiempo <12:
    hablar("Buenos Dias")
 if tiempo>=12 and tiempo <18:
    hablar("Buenas Tardes")
 if tiempo>=18 and tiempo <24:
    hablar("Buenas Noches")
 hablar("Tu asistente de Python al servicio, Como puedo ayudarte?")

def Enviaremail(para, contenido):
 servidor= smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
 servidor.ehlo()
 servidor.starttls()
 servidor.login("micorreo@gmail.com", "mi contraseña")
 servidor.sendmail("micorreo@gmail.com", para, contenido)
 servidor.close()

#Funcion para reconocimiento de voz
def Escuchar():
 r= sr.Recognizer()
 with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Escuchando...")
    r.pause_threshold=1 #Tiempo para escuchar
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1) #hace el proceso mas rapido
    audior=r.listen(source)
 try:
    print("Reconociendo...")
    query=r.recognize_google(audior, language="es")
 except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    hablar("Repite de nuevo...")
    return "None"
 return query

def Pantallazo():
 imagen= pyautogui.screenshot()
 imagen.save("C:/Users/diego/Pictures/Python/Pantallazo.png")

def EstadoDelSistema():
 uso_de_cpu= str(psutil.cpu_percent())
 frequencia_de_cpu= str(psutil.cpu_freq())
 #uso_de_disco= str(psutil.disk_usage(path=))
 hablar("El uso de CPU es de" + uso_de_cpu)
 hablar("La frequencia del procesador es" + frequencia_de_cpu)
 #hablar("La uso del disco es de" + uso_de_disco)

def Chistes():
 hablar(pyjokes.get_joke(language="es"))

async def Clima():
 cliente=python_weather.Client(format=python_weather.METRIC) 
 hablar("Di tu ciudad")
 ciudad= Escuchar()
 clima= await cliente.find(ciudad)
 hablar(ciudad)
 hablar(str(clima.current.temperature) + "grados centigrados")
 #traducir= Translator()
 #traducir.translate(text=clima.current.sky_text, dest="es", src="en").text
 #hablar(traducir)
 for forecast in clima.forecasts:
    hablar(str(forecast.date) + str(forecast.sky_text) + str(forecast.temperature))
 await cliente.close()

def Localizacion():
 miUbicacion=geocoder.ip(location="me")
 zonaCiudad=miUbicacion.city
 zonaState=miUbicacion.state
 zonaPais=miUbicacion.country
 print(miUbicacion)
 hablar(zonaCiudad + zonaState+ zonaPais)

#Funcion Principal
if __name__ == "__main__":
 Saludo()
 while True:
    query=Escuchar().lower()
    print(query)
    if "hora" in query:
        Hora()
    elif "fecha" in query:
        Fecha()
    elif "wikipedia" in query:
        hablar("Buscando...")
        wikipedia.set_lang("es")
        query=query.replace("wikipedia", "")
        resultado= wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
        hablar(resultado)
    elif "enviar email" in query:
        try:
            hablar("¿Para quien es el correo?")
            para= Escuchar()
            print(para)
            hablar(para)
            hablar("¿Que deberia decir el correo?")
            contenido= Escuchar()
            Enviaremail(para, contenido)
            hablar("El email ah sido enviado")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            hablar("Imposible enviar el email")
    elif "ir a sitio web" in query:
        hablar("Que sitio deberia yo buscar")
        navegadorpath= "C:/Users/diego/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/launcher.exe %s"
        busqueda= Escuchar().lower()
        print(busqueda)
        hablar(busqueda)
        wb.get(navegadorpath).open_new_tab(busqueda + ".com")
    elif "buscar en el navegador" in query:
        hablar("Que deberia yo buscar")
        navegadorpath= "C:/Users/diego/AppData/Local/Programs/Opera GX/launcher.exe %s"
        busqueda= Escuchar()
        print(busqueda)
        hablar(busqueda)
        wb.get(navegadorpath).open_new_tab("https://www.google.com/search?client=opera-gx&q="+busqueda+"&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8")
    elif "cerrar sesión" in query:
        os.system("shutdown - 1")
    elif "reiniciar sistema" in query:
        os.system("shutdown /r /t 1")
    elif "apagar sistema" in query:
        os.system("shutdown /s /t 1")
    elif "reproducir canciones" in query:
        directorio_canciones= "C:/Users/diego/Music"
        canciones= os.listdir(directorio_canciones)
        os.startfile(os.path.join(directorio_canciones, canciones[0]))
    elif "cerrar sesion" in query:
        os.system("shutdown - 1")
    elif "guardar un recordatorio" in query:
        hablar("¿Que deberia yo recordar?")
        data= Escuchar()
        hablar("Tu me diste a recordar" + data)
        recordar= open("data.txd", "w")
        recordar.write(data)
        recordar.close()
    elif "recuérdame algo" in query:
        recordar= open("data.txd", "r")
        hablar("Me pediste que te recordara que " + recordar.read())
    elif "pantallazo" in query:
        Pantallazo()
        hablar("¡¡Pantallazo Listo!!")
    elif "estado del sistema" in query:
        EstadoDelSistema()
    elif "chiste" in query:
        Chistes()
    elif "clima" in query:
        bucle=asyncio.get_event_loop()
        bucle.run_until_complete(Clima())
    elif "ubicación" in query:
        Localizacion()
    elif "apaga te" in query:
        hablar("Nos Vemos")
        quit()
    elif "apágate" in query:
        hablar("Adiós")
        quit()
    elif "apagar" in query:
        hablar("Chao")
        quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Significado del error

El error es fácil de reproducir:

```
None()
```

**Salida:** `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Este error quiere decir, que estás intentado llamar a un objeto `None` como si fuera un función, cuando `None` no es una función definida, que pueda ser llamada y se le puedan pasar parámetros. En tu caso una función sería, la función que tu has definido `hablar`, eso si es una función, y por tanto puede ser **llamada** (invocada).

### 2. ¿Qué puede estár ocurriendo?

Este error es muy común que se produzca, porque halla algúna función que esperas que devuelva un resultado, pero en realidad no es así. Por ejemplo:

```
def hola():
    print("Hola")

almacenamos_resultado_hola = hola()
print(almacenamos_resultado_hola)
#Intentamos ejecutar la función pero no se pueda
almacenamos_resultado_hola()
```

**Salida**:

```
None
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

También es posible, que una función tenga la posibilidad de devolver una función o NO con `if... else`. Por ejemplo

```
def hola():
    print("Hola")

def saludo(saludamos):
    if saludamos:
        return hola

#Nos retorna la función
saludar = saludo(True)
print(saludar())

#En este caso no, y estamos intentando ejecutarla
no_saludar = saludo(False)
no_saludar()
```

**Salida:**

```
Hola
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Como podemos ver la primera vez con `True` funciona y la siguiente no.

Se puede dar de más formas, por ejemplo con decoradores. El caso es que en alguna parte de tu código estás realizando esa operación (o las librerías que usas).

### 3. Soluciones

La solución es identificar en tu código, cuando estás llamando a `None` como si fuera una función y puedes hacer dos cosas.

1. Cambiar tú código para que no se de esa situación.
2. Si una vez identificado el error, consideras que la situación debe de darse utilizar un `try... except` para que tu programa siga funcionando

Comment: Vale eh leído tu aclaración y eh dado con el error y es una de las librerías que estoy importando (la librería de geocoder) la que me esta dando ese error, así que por ahora no la voy a usar y en el sitio de GitHub le comentare al creador de la librería del error para que lo revise, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Me alegra que te haya sido de ayuda! Puede que no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es marcando la respuesta como "respuesta correcta" y por qué no, darle un voto positivo!